# Avoid injection in SQL LIKE query in Node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, security, sql-injection

Several questions were asked on this topic. But I couldn't find the exact answer anywhere.
Will the code below cause sql injection? If yes how to escape it?

```
db.query('SELECT USER.id, USER.username FROM USER LEFT JOIN user_photo photo ON USER.id = photo.user_id WHERE USER.username LIKE "%' + search + '%"', (err, result) => {
   if (err) throw err
   res.send(result)
})
```

I've tried the code below with `mysql.escape()`. But SQL query is not working in this case:

```
db.query('SELECT USER.id, USER.username FROM USER LEFT JOIN user_photo photo ON USER.id = photo.user_id WHERE USER.username LIKE "%' + mysql.escape(search) + '%"', (err, result) => {
   if (err) throw err
   res.send(result)
})
```

Comment: Try replacement, most library has it. safest way would be parameterized query, but of course slower.

Comment: How do you expect it to work like?

Comment: @AnonyMouze, Parameterized queries are slower? You have measured this?

Comment: @BillKarwin  am not sure about the database execution, but there is extra steps in doing parameterized query most of languages i uses. So it is logically  slower.

Comment: In practice, the difference is much smaller than the query execution time. It's not a good reason to avoid using parameterized queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the LIKE pattern in the parameter that you pass to the query like so, the parameter will be safely escaped as documented [here](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values)

```
let search = "Terry";

let sql = `SELECT USER.id, USER.username FROM USER 
           LEFT JOIN user_photo photo 
           ON USER.id = photo.user_id WHERE USER.username LIKE ?`;

db.query(sql, [`%${search}%`], (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err
    res.send(result);
})
```